# Coupon code creation in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, coupon, coupon-codes

I have created a new discount coupon code (2014SALE) of 10% discount for a particular category (say Car). It is working fine. But my requirement is to create an another discount of $75 for a particular product (say Maruti) on the same category (Car) with the same coupon code (2014SALE).

That means if user applies code 2014SALE having any products under category car will get 10% discount on total price. But if user applies code 2014SALE having Maruti in the cart, he will get discount of flat $75.

Is it possible to create two different kind of discounts with the same coupon code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The table salesrule_coupon has a unique index on the coupon code, so only one global coupon code is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

Is it possible to add percentage discount coupon for a category except a certain product and then add another fix price discount coupon for that particular product?

If yes, please let me the know the procedure.